# Responsive-design integrated into hybrid-mobile application?

Tags: responsive-design, app-store, integration, hybrid-mobile-app

I was curious if there was a way to create a responsive-designed website that could be put on the app store as a hybrid-mobile application in which the hybrid-mobile application just opened the default browser of your phone, put it in full-screen mode, and then launched the website url to your responsive-designed website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is called a [Progressive Web Application](https://developers.google.com/web/progressive-web-apps/) and Google Android has supported them for a few years now.  [Apple iOS just began supporting](https://medium.com/@firt/progressive-web-apps-on-ios-are-here-d00430dee3a7) this with the most recent release of Mobile Safari.  The only problem is that you can't put these apps in the app stores.  Instead the users just get them by visiting the right page for the app and choosing to install it as an app on their phone.